# How to insert variable into javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to this. I want to insert variable (not text) into my code:

```
var events = {};
events[new Date("03/05/2019")] = new Event("Math", "green");
```

Now when you click text "Math" appears.

I want to insert variable - not directly as a text, but like this:

```
var subject = Math;
var events = {};
events[new Date("03/05/2019")] = new Event( ?subject? , "green");
```

to get the same result.

Comment: `subject` maybe ... ? Also `subject = Math` should probably be `subject = "Math"`

Comment: great, it works :D

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you get errors? If so, what errors? Try some things yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make `Math` a string, otherwise you are passing the reference `Math` as a parameter, and `Math` is an object provided by JavaScript.

You then just need to use the variable that it is assigned to (in this case `subject`) and pass that as a parameter to the `Event` class constructor.

```
var subject = 'Math';
var events = {};
events[new Date("03/05/2019")] = new Event(subject, "green");
```